# Java test specific property of an object using Collection.contains()

Tags: java

In Java how to test if a Collection of objects contains an object depending on one of its properties.

For example I would like to test if `Collection<myObjects>` contains an instance of myObjects which has myObjects.name = "myName".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to iterate and do the comparison.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a Map.

```
Map<String,myObjects> myMap = new HashMap<String,myObjects>();
myMap.put(myObject.name,myObject);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use apache collections, they provide a bunch of handy features including predicate:

```
public class MyPredicate implements Predicate {
  public boolean evaluate(Object input) {
    return (MyObject).name = "myName";
  }
}
```

then you can test your collection using :

```
   CollectionUtils.find(myCollection, new MyPredicate());
```

This will return the first object matching the predicate or null if none matches it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control on how the data is collected, you can also have some kind of "reverse index" on that property; The index can be a mapping between name and a set of myObjects with that name. This way, you can efficiently retrieve all items with a given name. You can add more indexes the same way.